# Regex library for VB6

Tags: regex, vb6

I need to write a program that can sift through specially-formatted text files (essentially CSV files with a fixed set of column types that have different delimiters for some columns ... comma in most places, colons in others) to search for formatting errors.  I figure regular expressions will be the way to go.

Is there a good regex library for VB6?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Regex COM component built into Windows. You can find a step by step on referencing and using it in your project at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html

Answer (score 2):

[Regex Buddy has a VB6 library](http://www.regexbuddy.com/vb.html)

I use this in Delphi and it's very good - and Jeff has raved about RegexBuddy on several occasions.

I can't speak for the VB implementation, but it's certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, VB6 didn't ship with a built-in regular expression library.  You can, however, use one provided by an ActiveX or COM library.  [See this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

*Other answers are correct, but link-only answers, so for convenience:*

In *File → References*, add the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library:

[image: screenshot]

Now you can use the library in your code:

```
Dim matcher As RegExp
Set matcher = New RegExp
matcher.Pattern = "^super cool string$"
If matcher.Test(someString) Then
    '...do something...
End If
```

As usual, [regular-expressions.info provides the best reference material](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html).